# XAML - Get ListView to use full height of grid cell

Tags: c#, xaml

I created a Grid in XAML with 2 Columns and 3 Rows, where the last of each shall have double the size of the rest:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Then I added a ScrollViewer containing a ListView to the grid, located in the biggest cell:

```
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
             <ListView x:Name="OutputListView" >
                    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                </ListView>
            </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

The ListView displays the items correctly, but although it is located in the big cell, it only has the height of one of the small cells, therefore not filling out the whole cell (surprisingly, the width matches the cell size).

If I place a TextBox within the cell, it fills it out completely, so my grid seems to be alright.

Any idea, how I get the ListView to use the full height of the cell?

EDIT:
taekahn's comment was the right hint. Here is my working version:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView x:Name="OutputListView" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping a `ListView` in a `ScrollViewer`? It already has one in its template.

Comment: I'm quite new to C# and XAML and that's how I found it in an example.

Comment: I first read your comment the wrong way, that is "ScrollViewer has a ListView in its template" which led to some problems.
But now, by using only the ListView everything works as intended (see my edit).

Comment: Glad I could be of some help.  :)

Answer (score 1):

When running your code, the `ScrollViewer` and the `ListView` take up the entire cell on my machine.
I did a side-by-side of the code as you posted it, and one with the backgrounds of the other cells colored for comparison.

[image: results]

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 RC, I  wonder if that has something to do with it (though it shouldn't and I guess it is more likely that my lack of experience with XAML and C# is the real cause).Thanks for the colored version, that's a good idea. I'll try that myself, maybe the problem then reveals itself.